# Position fixed #footer - mobile Safari (iPad) buggy behaviour

Tags: jquery, ipad, position, mobile-safari, fixed

I´m developing html+css for an iPad app.

To illustrate the problem I have made a simple dummy:

```
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <style>
        body {
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
            padding:0px;
            margin:0px;
            background:#333;    
        }
        #container {
            width:90%;
            margin:0 auto;
            background:#ccc;
            padding:10px;   
        }
        #footer {
            position:fixed;
            bottom:0px;
            height:100px;
            width:100%;
            background:red;
            text-align:center;  
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/>                                                        
</div>
    <div id="footer">

    </div>        
</body>
```

Try with iPad / Safari mobile and you will notice the the first time you scroll the footer (red block). It scrolls up out of position, untill you stop scrolling. On your second attempt it all works well.

When you reload the page it all happens again.

I think it´s the support for position fixed that is buggy.

Any ideas how to solve this? Perhaps with jQuery.

Comment: I don't see any problem on ipad 1 IOS 5.1. (Except when page opens red-bar flashes in the middle of the page then it is shown on the right place) What is your IOS version?

Comment: We are currently using iOS 6.0.1 (I add this since I work with Johan :-)). This also occur on the iPhone, so it is not an iPad specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jimbo above identified the problem and led me to the answer.

It worked with 100ms delay.

Here´s the final sollution that worked for me.

```
function fixJqmScrollBug() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, 100);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    fixJqmScrollBug();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the same issue experienced here [jQuery Mobile Fixed Footer Scrolls with Text One Time Then Stops in iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199258/jquery-mobile-fixed-footer-scrolls-with-text-one-time-then-stops-in-ios-app) ? If so it seems the little hack fixed the issue.

Comment: Alternatively does adding height=device-height to the meta viewport work?    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height">

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with the project I was working on. Instead of using:

```
#footer {
      position:fixed;
      bottom:0px;
      height:100px;
      width:100%;
      background:red;
      text-align:center;  
}
```

I used the following code and it really worked for me

```
#footer {
      position:absolute;
      bottom:0px;
      height:100px;
      width:100%;
      background:red;
      text-align:center;  
}
```